Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 22.04 to 24.04.1
I know the release was delayed until Aug 29th, but its now September and I still cannot upgrade to 24.04. This is Ubuntu Server.
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

This is post apt update / upgrade. Even did a reboot afterwards and tried again for good measure. Was the server LTS point release delayed (not sure if its a separate release train from the Desktop release)?

LOL, yesterday I tried an upgrade and do-release-upgrade offered the update (that then didn't work correctly due to package conflicts with PostgreSQL and PostGIS). Today I went to do it manually (dump the cluster, remove the packages, upgrade) and.. .lo and behold! No upgrades available!

Just adding in a note here that I spun up a 22.04 server VM, and during the install of the server it prompts you to upgrade to 24.04.  But skipping it and installing the 22.04 does not allow the do-release-upgrade to run.  Says no new development available.

On my machine, Ubuntu combines an announcement of 24.04.1 LTS with the message quoted above: ```New release '24.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
You have new mail.
Last login: Wed Sep  4 06:30:57 2024 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
user@snafu:~# sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.```

What is the Prompt= setting in your /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file?

@user535733 I have Prompt=lts (on 22.04.4 LTS) and would expect do-release-upgrade -c to offer an upgrade, but it does not. Indeed, yesterday a new release was shown as available upon login, but like @RobM I had some database-related preparations to do and waited until today…

Upgrade is paused for the time being.
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006225.html
Not sure which bug that is of all these, maybe the one that shows as "critical"
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader

According to Utkarsh Gupta on the mailing list in a reply to Michael Payne (one of the other answers here!):


It seems the file https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts was modified yesterday at 15:01 and no longer contains the Noble upgrade 24.04.1 LTS. Was it removed for a reason? do-release upgrade no longer works with the channel set to LTS.

That's correct - the upgrade was disabled due to a critical bug in
ubuntu-release-upgrader in the way it's using the apt solver. This is
being worked on and as soon as this is fixed, we'll re-enable the
upgrades.

I never saw an announcement, but Michael's answer has followup information and a link to the related issue.

Edit: Update from release mailing list
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006226.html
Edit again: Fix is out in the proposed branch.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-gcp/+bug/2078720
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/s/YMcOjexGNM

don't you wonder why the entry was removed though? Maybe even on purpose? I won't rush to upgrade my servers until things are clarified.

I strongly suspect they found out some critical bug that shows itself often enough to warrant fixing it before widespread upgrades start. They could have written something about it somewhere (I searched but I didn't find any official or unofficial statement on why the upgrade was yanked)

sure would be nice if they'd say something then. with no official statement i'm just left wondering what's going on

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006225.html  and you'll note "We're also working on an announcement post/mail so that people are aware." which hasn't yet been published (that I'm aware of)

Fix is out for testing https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-gcp/+bug/2078720

Fix isn't "likely" [expected] to be deemed stable until early last week last I heard   (for those wanting official link; https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/episode-236/ is the only current one meeting Ubuntu News standard where Alex Murray talks about it a few minutes (~4:45) into podcast

In fact, on the two different machines where I have tested it, do-release-upgrade when run normally offers no updates:
$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

But adding the -d switch for including development versions gives the result that would have been expected from the plain command:
$ do-release-upgrade -c -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '24.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

I have now successfully upgraded a 22.04.4 LTS (ARM64) virtual machine that I had locally to 24.04.1 LTS by simply running sudo do-release-upgrade -d.
As the release that is installed by sudo do-release-upgrade -d clearly identifies itself as "24.04.1 LTS", I presume that the upgrade was correct and that the -d switch is a good workaround for the current problem.
