do-release-upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS still no update available
I thought after the release of the 24.04.1 LTS version the upgrade from 22.04.4 LTS should be available. If I try a do-release-upgrade I always get the information There is no development version of an LTS available.
In the config file (/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades) I have set Prompt=lts Is there anything wrong with my system of is the upgrade path still not available?

Probably related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525477/unable-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-server-22-04-to-24-04-1, pointing to https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006225.html.

Is that the exact command you are using with no added options like -d?

From the ubuntu-release mailing list, 05 Sep 2024

[T]he upgrade was disabled due to a critical bug in ubuntu-release-upgrader in the way it's using the apt solver. This is being worked on and as soon as this is fixed, we'll re-enable the upgrades.


The upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 is currently held back by Canonical due to a critical bug with the apt resolver. More details can be found at e.g. this OMG Ubuntu news post.
However, using the -d option with sudo do-release-upgrade will trigger the upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, whereas the -d instructs the do-release-upgrade program to include development releases. Unless you know exactly what you are doing and can help yourself fixing the system in case the upgrade goes wrong, it is recommendable to stick to Ubuntu 22.04 until the bug is fixed and Canonical releases the upgrade path from 22.04 to 24.04 for all users.
